Two answers of a single integral
I'm trying to solve the following integral:
$\int{\frac{(x-1)}{\sqrt{x+4}}dx}$
To solve using substitution I do the following: Let $(x+4)=t^2$ and therefore, $dx=2tdt$.
Also, $x-1 = t^2-5$.
Substituting in the original integral, we get:
$2\int{\frac{(t^2-5)t}{\sqrt{t^2}}dt}$.
In the book I'm using the denometor of the above integral is simply written as $t$. However, I argue that it should be $|t|$ (absolute value of t).
After which taking cases, when $t<0$ and $t>0$, must give two answers, say $p$ and $-p$.
What's wrong here?
The following makes me argue that $\sqrt{t^2}$ must be $|t|$:

Edit: The question and its solution in the book: 

You are correct. When you solve your integral which contains the $t$ variable, you will notice that the function is not defined at $t=0$. In fact, you will have the $ sgn(t) $ in the solution. Wolfram shows this nicely: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5Bt%2C2%5D-5%5C%2841%29%2C%5Csqrt%5C%2840%29Power%5Bt%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2Ct%5D

@FriendlyNeighborhoodEngineer A $t$, you've missed. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=2Integrate%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5Bt%2C2%5D-5%5C%2841%29t%2C%5Csqrt%5C%2840%29Power%5Bt%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2Ct%5D and the $sgn(t)$ is gone.

@FriendlyNeighborhoodEngineer However, now we have a |t| in the answer. Does that mean the integral has two answers?

@M.Riyan answered nicely and clearly. So essentially, you are dealing with positive numbers, so you don't have to consider the absolute value.

@YvesDaoust , I edited the post to add the solution.

@YvesDaoust Nope. Not at all. Probably because it's a high school book and therefore such things are neglected by the author. (It's a 30yr old book, belonged to my father once)

Valid substitutions should be one-to-one maps. Here, the range of values of $x$ is $(-4, \infty)$. To ensure that the substitution $x=t^2-4$ is one-to-one requires you to choose a $t$-domain of either $(0, \infty)$ or $(-\infty, 0)$. Whichever of these you choose, as @M.Riyan points out, gives the same primitive when substituting back. The reason you don't normally see this stressed is that going ahead with many-to-one substitutions without thinking about restrictions on the domain of the substitution variable usually gives the correct answer - think of all those trig substitutions!
The general result is as follows.
If $f: (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $u: (c, d) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable with $u(c)=a$, $u(d)=b$, then $$\int_a^bf(x) dx =\int_c^d f(u(t)) u'(t) dt.$$ For this result, $u$ does not have to be one-to-one. So, for instance, $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx =\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 t}} \cos t \, dt=\int_0^{\frac{5}{2}\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 t}} \cos t \, dt$$ where $\sin$ is one-to-one on $(0, \frac{1}{2}\pi)$, but not on $(0, \frac{5}{2}\pi)$. When you try to complete the evaluation, however, the first gives $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\pi} \frac{1}{\cos t} \cos t \, dt=\frac{1}{2}\pi$$ and the second gives $$\int_0^{\frac{5}{2}\pi} \frac{1}{|\cos t |} \cos t\,  dt$$ which has to be evaluated in sub-intervals on which the substitution is one-to-one as $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\pi} \frac{1}{\cos t } \cos t \, dt+\int_{\frac{1}{2}\pi}^{\frac{3}{2}\pi} -\frac{1}{\cos t } \cos t \, dt+\int_{\frac{3}{2}\pi}^{\frac{5}{2}\pi} \frac{1}{\cos t } \cos t \, dt=\frac{1}{2}\pi-\pi+\pi=\frac{1}{2}\pi.$$
For indefinite integrals, therefore, it's sensible to use one-to-one substitutions because , when you substitute back at the end for the original variable it is much easier if you can just use the inverse of the substitution without worrying about which 'branch' you are on. In the example, using the substitution $x=\sin t$ with the domain of $t$ being $(-\frac{1}{2}\pi, \frac{1}{2}\pi)$ means that you don't need any modulus signs and you can just replace $t$ with $\arcsin x$: $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx =\int\frac{1}{\cos t} \cos t \, dt=t+c=\arcsin x + c.$$

Is the one to one relation between x and t required so that for every x there is a unique t and vice versa and therefore the answer to the integral in terms of t also becomes a function as it should be? Suppose if one to one relation isn't made between x and t, then the answer to the integral would not be a function, that is, for one input of x the outputs would be multiple. And therefore one to one relation between x and the substitute is mandatory. Is it the reason?

And, can we conclude that, if the answer to an integral has to be a function which it should be, then one to one relation is mandatory? And therefore, only a single answer to an integral always exists.?

Thanks for the edit, I feel it now.

The book says $t$ instead of $|t|$ because $t$ is always positive. You have considered $\sqrt{x+4}=t$, since $\sqrt {x+4}$ is always positive, so is $t$. So, it is not necessary to write it as $|t|$ and work with two types of values of it, say $-t$ and $t$. $-t$ was never in the actual integral, so why work with it?
As a reply to your comment, consider $t=-\sqrt{x+4}$, then $x-1=t^2-5$ and $dx=2tdt$. Upon substitution, we get:
$$2\int \frac{(t^2-5)t}{-t}dt=-2\int(t^2-5)dt=-2\left[\frac{t^3}3-5t\right]$$
$$=2\left[\frac 13(x+4)^{3/2}-5\sqrt{x+4}\right]$$
Considering the other way around, when $t=\sqrt{x+4}$, the integral is:
$$2\int \frac{(t^2-5)t}{t}dt=2\int(t^2-5)dt=2\left[\frac{t^3}3-5t\right]$$
$$=2\left[\frac 13(x+4)^{3/2}-5\sqrt{x+4}\right]$$
"After which taking cases, when $t<0$ and $t>0$, must give two answers, say $p$ and $−p$."
No it does not. It may be referred to as a redundant substitution.

I agree. However, taking $t^2 = x + 4$ gives $t = +or-\sqrt{x+4}$

Technically, by always positive you mean always non-negative.

Yes, I mean that actually

The simplest way is: avoid the substitution and observe that $${x-1\over \sqrt{x+4}}={(x+4)-5\over \sqrt{x+4}}=\sqrt{x+4}-{5\over \sqrt{x+4}}$$ Hence the result is $$ {2\over 3}(x+4)\sqrt{x+4}-10\sqrt{x+4}$$
